# CentOS Openstack Victoria repository disappeared

Tags: centos, openstack, centos8

A few days ago installing the Openstack Victoria Repo for CentOS 8 stopped to work. The packet can not be found by yum.

```
[foo@controller ~]$ sudo yum install centos-release-openstack-victoria
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:06 ago on Sat Dec 12 12:16:29 2020.
No match for argument: centos-release-openstack-victoria
Error: Unable to find a match: centos-release-openstack-victoria
```

Does anyone have an Idea what the problem here is?

Answer (score 0):

Someone probably goofed. The repo release file has a branch in GitHub and all the mirrors seem to have the RPMs.

You can report the problem on the CentOS-devel mailing list.

In the meantime you can work around it by manually downloading the release repo file.

```
[root@localhost ~]# curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rdo-infra/centos-release-openstack/victoria-rdo/CentOS-OpenStack.repo | sed 's/OPENSTACK_VERSION/victoria/g' > /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-OpenStack-victoria.repo
```